# Flip color range of heatmap in base R

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I am building a simple heat map in base R.
This is my matrix:

```
stleft = matrix( 
     c(0,5,5,2,6,8,4,6,9), 
     nrow=3, 
     ncol=3) 
colnames(stleft) <- c("Narrow","Wide", "Wider")
rownames(stleft) <- c("Person", "Object","Bare")
stleft
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
> stleft
       Narrow Wide Wider
Person      0    2     4
Object      5    6     6
Bare        5    8     9
```

To build the heat map I simply run:

```
heatmap(stleft, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none")
```

[image: heatmap]

As you can see the "0" (corresponding to the narrow/person cell) appears as a deep red while the "9" (corresponding to the wider/bare cell) appears as light yellow.

- How can I "flip" this range so that the "0" appears in a light color and the "9" in a deep color?
- Why is the image truncated? It appears truncated in the RStudio plot panel and it is saved truncated. I have tried to enlarge the plot panel in R Studio to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`heatmap()` (and `image()`) uses `heat.colors()` to generate the colors by default. You can supply your own colours if you want, f.ex. by using `heat.colors()`, just reversed.

```
par(oma=c(3, 0, 0, 3))
col <- rev(heat.colors(999))
heatmap(stleft, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none", col = col)
```

[image]